# how to implement a datepicker which can select multiple dates in angular 6?

Tags: angular

the function is that the users can select multiple date in the datepicker.
I have found ways to implement such datepicker for angualr >=7, using dateclass. However angular 6 doesnt have dateclass attribute.

Comment: My complete requirement is that I have an input field and a datepicker and if I open datepicker I will select one date and it will be seen in input field with cancel sign and if I want to add more dates I will open the dialogbox and select other date and it will also shown in input field with cancel sign and the dates I have selected previously will show selected in datepicker.

Comment: Your comment should just be part of your question. Also show what you have tried so far by adding some code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.